# Creating a Second Generation Managed Package with configuration link

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, beta-managed-package, second-generation-packaging

I am creating a second-generation managed package and Install,
After the Installing package there should be a link: which navigates to the lightning component present in the package and sets the configurations of a page from it.
This Link should be accessed outside of the package inside/beside the package name in the Installed Package page from setup.

How can I achieve it?.

Comment: I was wondering are there any new updates with respect to this in August 2021?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, we don't have the possibility to show a configuration Link on Second Generation Managed Package(2GP) as in First Generation Managed Package(1GP).
This is one of the drawbacks of 1GP to 2GP.